# Cronjob not running mysql script?

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

I've created a cronjob that runs every day at 13:00 as shown below.

```
0 13 * * * root /bin/sh /home/reconfigure.sh
```

Inside my reconfigure.sh file I delete several files first, which I know works because I can see they have been deleted. What then should happen is that I connect to a database and create the same files again using information from the database.

This all works fine when I run the script manually myself but in the cronjob it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my reconfigure.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name script_\* -exec rm {} \;

mysql -h"localhost" -u"USERNAME" -p"PASSWORD" "config" -s -N -e "SELECT * FROM configuration" | while read -r id name group
do
cat > script_$name.sh << EOF1
#!/bin/sh
### Do stuff here - cut out for posting
EOF1
/bin/chmod +x /home/script_$name.sh
done
```

As I said, I can run reconfigure.sh and it will delete the files connect to the database and create all the files, do what I have defined and even chmod the files. But when run in the cron it just doesn't work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to debug it is

```
0 13 * * * root /bin/sh /home/reconfigure.sh > /home/reconfigure.log
```

Check the reconfigure.log file to see what is the error.